# Using symbols to draw lines rather than line type

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the diet information of seven monkeys that details the proportion of each diet item in each monkeys diet with an SE.  The data are included here.

```
data <- structure(list(MonkeyID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L), .Label = c("P06", "P07", 
"P08", "P09", "P10", "P12", "P13"), class = "factor"), Diet = structure(c(3L, 
2L, 8L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 3L, 2L, 8L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 
9L, 3L, 2L, 8L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 3L, 2L, 8L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 
6L, 7L, 9L, 3L, 2L, 8L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 3L, 2L, 8L, 1L, 
5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 3L, 2L, 8L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 9L), .Label = c("Apple", 
"Bird", "Cherry", "Goats", "Orange", "Porcupine", "Raccoon", 
"SmChildren", "SmMamm"), class = "factor"), ObsProp = c(0.333333333, 
0, 0, 0.033333333, 0.366666667, 0.166666667, 0.033333333, 0.066666667, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.684931507, 0.315068493, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.022727273, 
0.840909091, 0.113636364, 0, 0, 0.022727273, 0, 0, 0, 0.016666667, 
0.916666667, 0.066666667, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.016129032, 0.032258065, 
0.080645161, 0.790322581, 0.064516129, 0, 0, 0.016129032, 0.083333333, 
0, 0, 0, 0.791666667, 0.125, 0, 0, 0, 0.105263158, 0, 0, 0, 0.657894737, 
0.210526316, 0, 0, 0.026315789), BootSD = c(0.086106917, 0, 0, 
0.032505407, 0.088036303, 0.067629445, 0.033002128, 0.046190006, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.05399944, 0.05399944, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.022101535, 
0.055554128, 0.04806202, 0, 0, 0.022399649, 0, 0, 0, 0.016603534, 
0.03591038, 0.032417222, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.016058474, 0.022618108, 
0.034249235, 0.051625307, 0.03101898, 0, 0, 0.015862183, 0.055436816, 
0, 0, 0, 0.082385021, 0.067258445, 0, 0, 0, 0.049480715, 0, 0, 
0, 0.076734249, 0.066770967, 0, 0, 0.026230342)), .Names = c("MonkeyID", 
"Diet", "ObsProp", "BootSD"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-63L))
```

and look like this

```
> head(data)
  MonkeyID       Diet    ObsProp     BootSD
1      P06     Cherry 0.33333333 0.08610692
2      P06       Bird 0.00000000 0.00000000
3      P06 SmChildren 0.00000000 0.00000000
4      P06      Apple 0.03333333 0.03250541
5      P06     Orange 0.36666667 0.08803630
6      P06      Goats 0.16666667 0.06762944
```

With this code

```
require(ggplot2)
pd <- position_dodge(0.5)
ColorBlind <- c("#999999", "#E69F00", "#56B4E9", "#009E73", "#F0E442", "#0072B2", "#D55E00", "#CC79A7")
fig <- ggplot(data)+
  geom_point(aes(x=Diet, y=ObsProp ,color=MonkeyID),position = pd, size = 2.75)+
  geom_errorbar(aes(x=Diet, ymin=(ObsProp - BootSD), ymax=(ObsProp + BootSD),colour=MonkeyID), position = pd, cex =1.25)+  
  ylab("Proportion of prey in diet")+  
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")+
  theme_bw()+
  scale_colour_manual(values =ColorBlind)+
  scale_linetype_manual(values=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7))+
  labs(color="Cougar ID")
fig
```

I can generate this figure.

[image: fig]

**Problem**: Color figures are expensive.  I need to distinguish between individual monkeys without color.  Simply mapping `MonkeyID` to a `linetype` does not produce discernible results (below).

```
fig <- ggplot(data)+
  geom_point(aes(x=Diet, y=ObsProp ,type = MonkeyID),position = pd, size = 2.75)+
  geom_errorbar(aes(x=Diet, ymin=(ObsProp - BootSD), ymax=(ObsProp + BootSD),lty = MonkeyID), position = pd, cex =1.25)+  
  ylab("Proportion of prey in diet")+  
  xlab("Prey species")+
  ggtitle("Proportion of prey species in individual monkey diets")+
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")+
  theme_bw()+
  scale_colour_manual(values =ColorBlind)+
  scale_linetype_manual(values=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7))+
  labs(color="Monkey ID")
fig
```

[image: BWfig]

**Question** Is it possible to use symbols to 'draw' lines?  For example, can I use a open squares (or open circles, open triangles, closed squares, etc) to depict a line that better distinguishes between individuals?

A stylized and simplified version of what I am looking for (for Goats only) would look like this:

[image]

**EDIT:**I am less interested in the shape of the point the depicts each individual. More important is the `geom_errorbar` for each individual.  If the `geom_errorbar` is unique to each individual (like above) then the `geom_point` for each individual is less important and could even be left out to ease interpenetration.  In addition the ggplot `shape palette can deal with a maximum of 6 discrete values because more than 6 becomes difficult to discriminate`

Any thoughts on how to achieve this goal or other ideas to clearly distinguish between individuals (without color) would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: how about `geom_point(aes(x=Diet, y=ObsProp ,shape=MonkeyID),...)` ?

Comment: see edits/added detail in the post

Comment: I think what you want, while not unreasonable, is going to be very difficult to achieve (especially within `ggplot`). It is possible to use >6 shapes in ggplot, you just need to specify `scale_shape_manual()`.  Hopefully someone else will be more helpful, but I'm guessing that setting point shapes will be about the best you can do.

Comment: ... you could also select a few different grayscales, and open vs closed symbols, for maximum distinguishability ...

Comment: Thanks Ben! Your comments helped me to rethink me problem. Very helpful!

Comment: You can answer the question with suggestions Ben proposed and accept the answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comments of Ben Bolker were very helpful. Indeed, I think changing the desired outcome is the best option here. The code below effectively serves as an answer to my own question.   I guess posting my own answer is the best way to show the post as closed.

```
 fig <- ggplot(data)+
      geom_point(aes(x=Diet, y=ObsProp ,shape = MonkeyID),position = pd, size = 3)+
      geom_errorbar(aes(x=Diet, ymin=(ObsProp - BootSD), ymax=(ObsProp + BootSD),lty = MonkeyID), position = pd)+  
      ylab("Proportion of prey in diet")+  
      xlab("Prey species")+
      ggtitle("Proportion of prey species in individual monkey diets")+
      theme(legend.position = "bottom")+
      theme_bw()+
      scale_linetype_manual(values=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1))+
      scale_shape_manual(values =c(19,6,15,5,1,8,17))+
      labs(color="Monkey ID")
    fig
```

[image]